# Delete trigger to delete child records

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

So, I have two tables.
One is sales_order (no_so VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY)
The other is status_so (no_so REFERENCES to sales_order)

I want the no_so from status_so is deleted if I delete the no_so in sales_order. So, I create the trigger to solve the problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_sales_order
ON sales_order
FOR DELETE
AS
   DELETE FROM status_so 
   WHERE status_so.no_so IN (SELECT deleted.no_so FROM deleted)
```

after that I run this code

```
DELETE FROM sales_order WHERE no_so = 'SO004'
```

and I still got an error, it says

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_status_so_sales_order". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.status_so", column 'no_so'.

Comment: The FK constraint is checked **before** your trigger is called, because by default its a **after** trigger. Its easier to set the FK constraint to cascade.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the suggestion! I am also thinking about using cascade, but now I already got the answer

Comment: Cascade is a much better option than a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> OR | AFTER FOR or AFTER specifies that the DML trigger fires only when
> all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have launched
> successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks
> must also succeed before this trigger fires.

You need to create `instead of` delete trigger and handle the deletions from the both table in the correct order there.

Comment: thank you so much! my code now runs very well as i expected.